# Infinite request with a big URL php-fpm

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, php-fpm

I have a zend  application running in lenp stack. Nginx 1.18, php 7.4.26,Ubuntu 20.04.
For this app I'm using ec-2 AWS and a database in RDS.

So,  the problem is.

I have some big queries who as passed in URL, like
https://example.com/basico/gestao-produtos/listagem/filtro-filtro-produto/cerv/filtro-produtos-ativo/S/filtro-filtro-barra_meses/S/filtro-avancado/SIM/filtro-filtro-id_lojas/1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-22-23-24-25-26-27-28-29-30-31-32-33-34-35-36-37-38-39-40-41-42-43-44-45-46-47-48-49-50-51-52-53-54-55-56-57-58-59-60-61-62-63-64-65-66-67-68-69-70-71-72-73-74-75-76-77-78-79-80-81-82-83-84-85-86-87-88-89-90-91-92-93-94-95-96-97-98-99-101-102-103-104-105-106-107-108-109-110-111-112-115-114-116-117-118-119-120-121-122-123-124-125-126-127-128-129-130-131-132-133-134-135-136-137-138-139-140-141-142-143-144-145-146-147-148-149-150-151-152-21-153-154-155-156-158-157/filtro-colunas/loja-abc_unidade-ean-descricao_comercial-sabor-marca-familia-compra-qtd_acumulada_consolidada-qtd_saida_media-custo-preco-margem_cadastrada-margem_bruta-margem_markup-margem_liquida/filtro-tamanhos/50-79-26-59-35-37-43-42-86-113-35-86-87-64-52-63/filtro-ordem-campo/3/filtro-ordem-direcao/asc.

And when i execute  something like that fpm simply not return anything. If I set the timeout to 10 hours,  the request will be running for the 10 hours, them nginx show the timeout. In apache+php-mod environment, this request was processed in about  20 S.

What  I am missing?

php-fpm.conf and www.conf are in default distributors version, I only changed php INi.
I already increased  nginx-body, proxy, everything who you can think. I also tried switching from nginx to apache +mpm-event+fpm, fpm return the samy error.
On  minor quries the fpm work's like a charm,  but on tha't big queries not work  att all
Thank you for any help;

Comment: You need to look into the SQL queries your application makes to the database and see how the queries cause this long duration for the queries.

Comment: Sorry, your point do not make any sence. The querie was the samy  who as good processed with apache+ mod php.